# Qt MacOs application crashes on exit with dyld::fastBlindLazySymbol and sold_stub_binder

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm using Qt 5.12.1 clang 64 bit on MacOs 10.13.6. The problem is that when quitting the application the program crashes but I really don't know why. It's a porting from windows to Mac so I've never had a step where the program didn't crash.

Everything I know is that when in debug it stucks here:

```
0x100e1c52a                   48 8b 80 40 01 00 00          movq 0x140(%rax), %rax
0x100e1c531  <+    7>         48 8b 15 98 8c 04 00          movq 0x48c98(%rip), %rdx # dyld::gLibSystemHelpers
0x100e1c538  <+   14>         48 85 d2                      testq %rdx, %rdx
0x100e1c53b  <+   17>         74 0a                         je 0x100e1c547 # <+72>
0x100e1c53d  <+   19>         48 8b 4a 08                   movq 0x8(%rdx), %rcx
0x100e1c541  <+   23>         4c 8b 42 10                   movq 0x10(%rdx), %r8
0x100e1c545  <+   27>         eb 05                         jmp 0x100e1c54c # <+77>
0x100e1c547  <+   29>         31 c9                         xorl %ecx, %ecx
0x100e1c549  <+   31>         45 31 c0                      xorl %r8d, %r8d
0x100e1c54c  <+   34>         48 8d 15 35 8b 04 00          leaq 0x48b35(%rip), %rdx # dyld::gLinkContext
0x100e1c553  <+   41>         44 89 f6                      movl %r14d, %esi
0x100e1c556  <+   44>         ff d0                         callq *%rax
0x100e1c558  <+   46>         5b                            popq %rbx
0x100e1c559  <+   47>         41 5e                         popq %r14
0x100e1c55b  <+   49>         5d                            popq %rbp
0x100e1c55c  <+   50>         c3                            retq 
0x100e1c55d  <+   51>         48 8d 3d 00 f1 02 00          leaq 0x2f100(%rip), %rdi # "dyld: %s\n"
0x100e1c564  <+   58>         48 8d 1d 50 f1 02 00          leaq 0x2f150(%rip), %rbx # "fast lazy binding from unknown image"
0x100e1c56b  <+   65>         31 c0                         xorl %eax, %eax
0x100e1c56d  <+   67>         48 89 de                      movq %rbx, %rsi
0x100e1c570  <+   70>         e8 d3 d3 ff ff                callq 0x100e19948 # dyld::log(char const*, ...)
0x100e1c575  <+   75>         48 89 df                      movq %rbx, %rdi
0x100e1c578  <+   78>         e8 a3 fd ff ff                callq 0x100e1c320 # dyld::halt(char const*)
0x100e1c57d  <+   83>         48 89 c3                      movq %rax, %rbx
0x100e1c580  <+   86>         83 fa 01                      cmpl $0x1, %edx
0x100e1c583  <+   89>         75 2c                         jne 0x100e1c5b1 # <+178>
0x100e1c585  <+   91>         48 89 df                      movq %rbx, %rdi
0x100e1c588  <+   94>         e8 87 1c 02 00                callq 0x100e3e214 # __cxa_begin_catch
0x100e1c58d  <+   99>         48 89 c3                      movq %rax, %rbx
0x100e1c590  <+  102>         48 8d 3d fe f0 02 00          leaq 0x2f0fe(%rip), %rdi # "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: %s\n"
0x100e1c597  <+  109>         31 c0                         xorl %eax, %eax
0x100e1c599  <+  111>         48 89 de                      movq %rbx, %rsi
0x100e1c59c  <+  114>         e8 a7 d3 ff ff                callq 0x100e19948 # dyld::log(char const*, ...)
0x100e1c5a1  <+  119>         48 89 df                      movq %rbx, %rdi
0x100e1c5a4  <+  122>         e8 77 fd ff ff                callq 0x100e1c320 # dyld::halt(char const*)
0x100e1c5a9  <+  127>         48 89 c3                      movq %rax, %rbx
0x100e1c5ac  <+  130>         e8 d7 1c 02 00                callq 0x100e3e288 # __cxa_end_catch
0x100e1c5b1  <+  135>         48 89 df                      movq %rbx, %rdi
0x100e1c5b4  <+  138>         e8 c7 e6 02 00                callq 0x100e4ac80 # _Unwind_Resume
0x100e1c5b9  <+  143>         55                            pushq %rbp
0x100e1c5ba  <+  144>         48 89 e5                      movq %rsp, %rbp
0x100e1c5bd  <+  147>         48 89 3d ec 8c 04 00          movq %rdi, 0x48cec(%rip) # dyld::sUndefinedHandler
0x100e1c5c4  <+  154>         5d                            popq %rbp
0x100e1c5c5  <+  155>         c3                            retq 
0x100e1c5c6  <+  156>         55                            pushq %rbp
0x100e1c5c7  <+  157>         48 89 e5                      movq %rsp, %rbp
0x100e1c5ca  <+  160>         48 89 d0                      movq %rdx, %rax
0x100e1c5cd  <+  163>         48 89 f1                      movq %rsi, %rcx
0x100e1c5d0  <+  166>         31 f6                         xorl %esi, %esi
0x100e1c5d2  <+  168>         48 89 ca                      movq %rcx, %rdx
0x100e1c5d5  <+  171>         48 89 c1                      movq %rax, %rcx
0x100e1c5d8  <+  174>         5d                            popq %rbp
0x100e1c5d9  <+  175>         e9 00 00 00 00                jmp 0x100e1c5de # dyld::findExportedSymbol(char const*, bool, ImageLoader::Symbol const**, ImageLoader const**)
0x100e1c5de  <+  180>         55                            pushq %rbp
```

And in the debugger I get:

- dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader * *, unsigned long) (x86_64)/usr/lib/dyld
- dyld_stub_binder (x86_64) /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

[image]

That's all I know about the crash. Does somebody knows what the previous lines mean? Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

********************* UPDATE **********************

Thanks to Sergio I managed to use the Address Sanitizer and this is the output:

```
    AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==25849==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00017e000378 (pc 0x00010983e52a bp 0x7ffeee5ea470 sp 0x7ffeee5ea460 T0)
==25849==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x10983e529 in dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) (dyld:x86_64+0x4529)
    #1 0x7fff56bfc291 in dyld_stub_binder (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1291)
    #2 0x1118ab007  (<unknown module>)
    #3 0x10695656a in QSqlDatabasePrivate::~QSqlDatabasePrivate() (QtSql:x86_64+0x556a)
    #4 0x106957140 in QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase() (QtSql:x86_64+0x6140)
    #5 0x10335a673 in T_AnalisiDati::~T_AnalisiDati() t_analisidati.cpp:35
    #6 0x10335a71e in T_AnalisiDati::~T_AnalisiDati() t_analisidati.cpp:33
    #7 0x7fff56ca8eec in __cxa_finalize_ranges (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x5deec)
    #8 0x7fff56ca91fd in exit (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x5e1fd)
    #9 0x7fff56bfc01b in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x101b)

==25849==Register values:
rax = 0x000000017e000238  rbx = 0x00000001118ab008  rcx = 0x0000000000000000  rdx = 0x0000000000000000  
rdi = 0x00006100000ca040  rsi = 0x00000000000001c6  rbp = 0x00007ffeee5ea470  rsp = 0x00007ffeee5ea460  
 r8 = 0x00007ffeee5ea7c0   r9 = 0x00007ffeee5ea7c0  r10 = 0x00007fff8f6280c8  r11 = 0x00000001118ab008  
r12 = 0x0000619000007380  r13 = 0x0000000000000002  r14 = 0x00000000000001c6  r15 = 0x00000000000002a0  
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (dyld:x86_64+0x4529) in dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long)
==25849==ABORTING
```

T_Analisi is a QThread that uses a QSqlDatabase. The object is global (I know it's a bad thing, but I didn't know it was when I start the project) can this be the reason why the application crashes? Or there is something else that I'm missing from the address sanitizer?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @SergioMonteleone I've updated the question with the stack trace. That's all I get there. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Oh that's all? Two questions then: 1) Does it also crash if you run your app withtout the debugger? 2) Did you enable the "Use debug version of frameworks" option in your "Run settings" in QtCreator ?

Comment: @SergioMonteleone Yes, my app also crashes if I run without the debugger. I did not enable that option, should I enable it?

Comment: Well enabling that option will let the debugger use the debug versions of the frameworks used by your app (including Qt) so if the crash is happening there you should end up with a nicer stack trace at the least. I've seen crashes like this when people try to use set a static QIcon for their app, but in this case you should have a QIconEngine call in your stack trace...

Comment: @SergioMonteleone I tried to set that variable but nothing change, I keep getting the same stack trace. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: It may be heap corruption. Try to run it with the address sanitizer, it may show up there

Comment: @SergioMonteleone I tried with the address sanitizer as in this [link](https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/04/17/using-gccs-4-8-0-address-sanitizer-with-qt) but nothing changes on the output. Anyway thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That link is quite old. You should just add `CONFIG += sanitizer sanitize_address sanitize_leak sanitize_undefined` to your .pro file, compile in release and run it. If some errors are detected, the program will immediately close and asan will print out its output. Otherwise, it will print out its messages when you close your program (e.g. showing unreleased bytes, etc).

Comment: @SergioMonteleone Thank you very much! I managed to use the address sanitizer and now I've updated the question with the address sanitizer output!

Comment: in general QSqlDatabase classes are reentrant but not thread safe. Accessing a QSqlDatabase object instanced globally (hence, on the main thread) from another thread can cause all sorts of unexpected behaviour. If you need help in structuring your program I suggest to post another (detailed) question, as this thread is starting to get messy :)